# API authentication without SSL

Tags: security, rest, authentication, oauth

I'm writing an API that will be hosted without SSL support and I need a way to authenticate the requests. Each client would have a different ID, but if requests were authorised with that, anyone with a packet sniffer could forge requests. Is it possible to make a secure system WITHOUT relying on SSL?

(Some thoughts I had included OAuth, could that be implemented?)

Many thanks

Comment: Why can't you use SSL???

Comment: @ircmaxell my (free) web host doesn't allow it. I'm not going to get a host with SSL.

Comment: If your *free* web host doesn't support SSL, then maybe you shouldn't run anything with sensitive data on it.

Comment: This is only a small project, and doesn't warrant paid hosting. What I'm looking for is authentication, not encryption. The data itself isn't sensitive.

Comment: The authentication credentials are sensitive, if you're concerned about packet sniffers or MITM, etc.; er go, you need SSL.

Comment: So does oauth work without ssl?

Comment: @LukeMoll: Define work. A password form works as well, even if the credentials are right below it. Technically the form still asks for a password. So why dou you need authentication, if you don't need it?

Comment: I need authentication, aka to know that the request came from a legitimate client, but not encryption. I need to know where it came from, not that the contents were transferred privately.

Answer (score 2):

Have each client cryptographically sign its requests with a client-specific key. Verify the signature on the server.

Using cryptography pretty simple. The main challenge is setting up the clients' keys. It'll be hard to do that securely without using SSL. There's no information in the question about how you set up client IDs, so I don't know if it's secure enough to set up keys at that point as well.

It's also going to be a problem if you serve the client code without SSL.
But hey, it's just an API you're building. Maybe the code that interacts with it is served over HTTPS. Or maybe the code is stored locally on the client.

I feel like a lot of people are going to complain about this answer though.

Comment: Thanks! The code isn't a problem, i have complete control over the client and server. If i was to hard-code the public/private keys into the clients/server, then as long as the incoming message from a client decodes with one of the keys, it's a legitimate message. Would that solve the key distribution?

Comment: Yeah, if you can personally hard-code the keys, and not send them over the wire at all, then it should be fine. The whole thing sounds much more doable given that you have complete control over the clients as well.